# rss feed, not automatically updated

Tags: android, rss

I wrote my own rss-feed for a guestbook from my website so that, with a simple rss-reader on my android-phone, I get a notification as soon as someone posted something in the guestbook.
however, my phone doesn't seem to recognize any updates; when I initially download the xml file, everything seems ok, but I never get any update, while there are some new messages, few times a day. Did I forget some parameter or something which tells my phone that there are new messages?

my code look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>PrivateRssFeed</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    <description>Private RSS-Feed</description>
    <language>nl-nl</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 09 Nov 2011 14:36:02 +0100</lastBuildDate>
    <pubDate>Wed, 09 Nov 2011 14:35:00 +0100</pubDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2011 Me</copyright>

    <item>
        <title>Person1</title>
        <description><![CDATA[This is some random text]]></description>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 09 Nov 2011 14:35:00 +0100</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Person2</title>
        <description><![CDATA[another random text]]></description>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 09 Nov 2011 14:34:00 +0100</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it :-)
the GUID seemed to be necessary for some readers to distinguish different items